C++ Mocking class members without dependency injection - is it possible?
Given the following code example which represents a simplification of a much larger project:
class IEaterOfCake
{
    public:
        virtual void EatCake() = 0;
};

class CakeMaker
{
    public:
        CakeMaker(IEaterOfCake & e) : mCakeEater(e) {}
        void MakeCake() { mCakeEater.EatCake(); }
    protected:
        IEaterOfCake & mCakeEater;
};

class HungryMan : public IEaterOfCake
{
    public:
        HungryMan() : mCakeMaker(*this) {}
        void HaveLunch() { mCakeMaker.MakeCake(); }
        virtual void EatCake() override {/* mmmm cake */};
    private:
        CakeMaker mCakeMaker;
};

int main()
{
    HungryMan m;
    m.HaveLunch();
}

I can nicely unit test CakeMaker with a test like:
TEST(sometest)
{
    class TestEater : public IEaterOfCake
    {
        virtual void EatCake() override {/* test cake is yummy */};
    } t;
    CakeMaker cm(t);
    cm.MakeCake();
}

Now, I would like to test HungryMan with a mock CakeMaker.  It is too complex to try test HunrgyMan and CakeMaker as a single unit.  In practice HungryMan has several internal classes feeding into it in a similar way.  The number of possibilities goes up exponentially!
Dependency injection of a CakeMaker (or interface to) would be ideal, but the hope was to hide them inside the HungryMan class.  And I am not sure how to make sure references to teh dependencies would be initialised at construction, as those dependencies also need to reference the Hungry man .  Note that 'new' cannot be used in this project, dynamic allocation is not allowed.
I am after suggestions on how to better structure this project so that HungyMan can be unit tested with a mock/test implementation.  Currently I conditionally compile in a different type for mCakeMaker (MockCakeMaker).  But I still have the issue where mCakeMaker is private and inaccessible to manipulate for testing.
I hope I explained OK, I struggled a bit!

For dependency injection, the constructor for HungryMan should be passed in a std::unique_ptr<ICakeMaker> which it then stores as a member variable.

@Eljay "…dynamic allocation is not allowed".

Since dynamic allocation is not allowed, pass ICakeMaker& for HungryMan's constructor, and store a non-owning ICakeMaker* member variable in HungryMan.

If dynamic memory allocation is not allowed, you may be able to solve this using, static polymorphism (class templates and concepts)

I am not sure storing a pointer helps.  The ICakeMaker needs to be initialised with a reference to a HungryMan (IEaterOfCake).  But the Hungry man cant exists at that point if the ICakeMaker is going to be passed to it at construction.  Seems a SetCakeMaker() function would be required which ruins all the niceness of reference members set at construction time.

You can template the class:
template <typename TCakeMaker>
class HungryManT : public IEaterOfCake
{
public:
    HungryManT() : mCakeMaker(*this) {}

    template <typename... Ts>
    HungryManT(std::in_place_t, Ts&&... args) : mCakeMaker(*this, std::forward<Ts>(args)...)
    {}

    void HaveLunch() { mCakeMaker.MakeCake(); }
    void EatCake() override {/* mmmm cake */};
private:
    TCakeMaker mCakeMaker;
};

using HungryMan = HungryManT<CakeMaker>;

Then in Unittest
using HungryManTest = HungryManT<CakeMakerMock>;

I have added a constructor to initialize mCakeMaker. Then mCakeMaker can be initialized as you want.
Note: I use extra "prefix" std::in_place_t to avoid unconstrained variadic constructor which might be problematic (as matching copy constructor from non-const lvalue, ...).

But I still have the issue where mCakeMaker is private and inaccessible to manipulate for testing.

The above constructor should allow to avoid that issue.
Else there are several ways to access private members (even legally):

friend
With some "black magic".


Thanks for the detailed suggestion.  I did muck around with templates but at the time it didn't solve the private member issue for testing.  I will have to do some research to understand that constructor as it is above my c++ pay grade!

@AshleyDuncan: I meant something like CakeMakerMock::CakeMakerMock(IEaterOfCake &, std::function<void(CakeMakerMock&)> init) { init(*this) } with usage HungryManTest t(std::in_place, [&](auto& mock){ EXPECT_CALL(mock, MakeCake()); });
